# Strange thing happened in oracle database

Tags: database, oracle

I am using Oracle database for more than half year. Today one row of the data is not able to update. I didn't get any error or anything even from the SQL developer. When I try to update, always get one row updated, and I did commit.

But when I try to query, I get the old value again. Only this one entry has this problem.

Could anyone please give me some suggestion?

Comment: 1) You run the query in the same session? If yes, probably Sathya is right. 2) Are you sure you are querying the same database/table?

Comment: Did you update the `dual` table?

Comment: How do you execute the update?  How do you know it succeeds?  How do you query the data?

Answer (score 3):

My guess is there's a trigger on the table which resets the value. Without looking at your  DML statements & table structures there's no way to comprehensively answer this.

To find out if you have a trigger on the table:

```
SELECT trigger_name 
FROM all_triggers 
WHERE table_name = '<whatever>';
```

Comment: Another option is that the table is actually a view, and an instead-of trigger is handling the update.

Answer (score 2):

There is something wrong with your code base.  There is no way we can diagnose it as we arehic. not telepat

So you will need to debug it.  SQL Developer has tools which can help you with this.  [Find out more](http://st-curriculum.oracle.com/obe/db/11g/r2/prod/appdev/sqldev/plsql_debug/plsql_debug_otn.htm).

If you don't understand how your own application works I suggest you start [by profiling your code](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/viewlets-082331.html).  This will tell you all the programs which fire when you run your update.  I agree with the suggestion regarding triggers, but it is just a guess.